# Compare two excel columns in two different table and write in second table on another column if match

Tags: python, excel, pandas

there are two Excel tables, the first table has a long name of the **signals** and a short **new_name**, the second only has a long name of the **signals**.

I'm trying to write a python script that does this work

```
loop1 # for Table1
    loop2 # for Table2
        if Table 1.signal[i]==Table 2.signal[j] then 
               Table2.new_name[j]==Table1.new_name[i]
        else Table2.new_name[j]=="-"
```

Here is the python code that I wrote, something is wrong with it!

```py
import pandas as pd

# ____________Open XLSX________________
def open_xlsx(_file_dir):
    _DataFrame = pd.read_excel(_file_dir, engine="openpyxl")
    _DataFrame.fillna('', inplace=True)
    return _DataFrame

# _____________________________________

signal_source_input = r"Table1.xlsx"
signal_source_output = r"Table2.xlsx"
signal_list_old = open_xlsx(signal_source_input)
signal_list_new = open_xlsx(signal_source_output)
arr = {}
for i in range(0, len(signal_list_old)):
    x = signal_list_old.iat[i, 3]
    for j in range(0, len(signal_list_new)):
        y = signal_list_new.iat[j, 3]
        if y == x:
            arr[j] = signal_list_old.iat[i, 22]
        else:
            arr[j] = "-"
print(arr)
# signal_source_list_new.to_excel(r"Table2.xlsx")
```

Table1

| n | signals | new_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | room1 window1 open | open |
| 1 | room2 window1 close | close |
| 2 | lighting control auto | auto |
| 3 | boiler temperature 5 error | error |

Table2

| n | signals | new_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 160 | room1 window1 open | open |
| 161 | room2 window1 close | close |
| 162 | ... ... ..abc voltage | - |
| 163 | ... ... .. error | - |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 222 | lighting control auto | auto |
| 223 | boiler temperature 5 error | error |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1['signals']))
df2["new_name"] = (df2.merge(df1, left_on=df2['signals'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False),
                   right_on='signals', how='left')['new_name_y']
                  )
```

Output:

```
     n                     signals new_name
0  160          room1 window1 open     open
1  161         room2 window1 close    close
2  162       ... ... ..abc voltage      NaN
3  163            ... ... .. error      NaN
4  222       lighting control auto     auto
5  223  boiler temperature 5 error    error
```